# ExTAPI: lineRegister returns before line is registered

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, tapi

I am using the extended TAPI function [lineRegister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922980.aspx) to register a GPRS radio on the network after powering the radio on using `lineSetEquipmentState`.  The `lineRegister` function is returning successfully before the network is actually registered.

The asynchronous `lineRegister` function first returns a positive number indicating the function succeeded.  I then wait for a `LINE_REPLY` callback from TAPI.  The 'dwParam1' value matches the initial return value of `lineRegister`, indicating this is the asynchronous reply to my previous `lineRegister` call.  The `dwParam2` value is set to 0, which MSDN says indicates the function succeeded.

I then try to connect to the GPRS network but the connection fails.  I have added code to call lineGetRegisterStatus in the LINE_REPLY for lineRegister, and I can confirm the radio is not yet registered.  Is there any way to be notified when the network is successfully registered and usable?  It seems broken to have to poll for network registration when there is an asynchronous API and notification system available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the TAPI implementation is very OEM dependent. You may find another device where it works the way you expect. But, if this is the one that you expect your application will be used on, then you will probably have to poll.

-PaulH